# Get-SqlInstance connection failure

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Test-Connection reaches the server successfully. What might be the root cause of:

```
>Get-SqlInstance -ServerInstance 'DEVSQL02'
Get-SqlInstance : Failed to connect to server DEVSQL02.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SqlInstance -ServerInstance 'DEVSQL02'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DEVSQL02:String) [Get-SqlInstance], ConnectionFailureException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectionToServerFailed,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetSqlInstanceCommand
```

From `help Get-SqlInstance`.

```
SYNTAX
    Get-SqlInstance [[-Credential] <PSCredential>] [-ConnectionTimeout <Int32>] [-Script] [-ServerInstance <String[]>] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Must PowerShell Remoting be enabled? Is port 1433 involved?

Using PowerShell 5.1.14409.1018 on Windows 7 Professional.

SqlServer module 21.1.18068.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code? Preferably a complete script up to an including the breaking line

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - Revised the code to one line. This is the breaking line.

Comment: I'm running PowerShell 5.1 (Build 14393 Rev 2828) on Windows 10 and it says that -ServerInstance is an invalid parameter.

Comment: Well the error message says "Failed to connect" which usually means that it can't connect. You will have to have port 1433 open. Try connecting with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and see what error you get.